# What is an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, mobile

I'm a beginner to Android Development, Can anyone please explain what is exactly an 'Activity' means in Android ? Is that similar to a 'Page' of an Android Application ?

Comment: Yes, kind of. But there should be heaps of tutorials out there, that would explain it.

Comment: all right @AlbAtNf  :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB.NET or C#, but thanks for the info @Hrundi V. Bakshi

Comment: ok, my mistake. But please help me as I did it without knowing :)

Comment: please refer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136096/what-is-an-activity-in-android) to more detailed answers and discussion.

Comment: please refer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136096/what-is-an-activity-in-android) for more answers and a discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain what is exactly an 'Activity' means in Android ?

An activity is your main "coarse" unit of user interface. It is roughly analogous to a screen, page, window, or other similar construct in other GUI environments.

Or, to quote [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html):

> An Activity is an application component that provides a screen with which users can interact in order to do something, such as dial the phone, take a photo, send an email, or view a map. Each activity is given a window in which to draw its user interface. The window typically fills the screen, but may be smaller than the screen and float on top of other windows.
>
> An application usually consists of multiple activities that are loosely bound to each other. Typically, one activity in an application is specified as the "main" activity, which is presented to the user when launching the application for the first time. Each activity can then start another activity in order to perform different actions. Each time a new activity starts, the previous activity is stopped, but the system preserves the activity in a stack (the "back stack"). When a new activity starts, it is pushed onto the back stack and takes user focus. The back stack abides to the basic "last in, first out" stack mechanism, so, when the user is done with the current activity and presses the Back button, it is popped from the stack (and destroyed) and the previous activity resumes. (The back stack is discussed more in the Tasks and Back Stack document.)

Comment: Thank You so much @CommonsWare :) That was helpful.